# I need to check the arrays having same objects or more than same in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have variable in php , first is `$needed` and second is `$whatwehave` so the objects in arrays is like that =>

```
$needed=['name','family','job'];
$whatwehave=['name','family','job'];
```

The thing that i want is available using `for` but I am looking for a better way.

The thing that i want is checking if the needed arrays exist in `$whatwehave` say 0 and if its not exist say 1 and if you don't know what is the needed array its stacked in `$needed` its very simple and i think there is a code in `PHP` for doing this like `in_array($array1,$array2)` or something else

My way is this :

```
$error=0;
for($i=0;$i<=(count($needed)-1);$i++){
    if(!in_array($needed[$i],$whatwehave)){
        $error=1;
    }
}
echo $error;
```

The way that i looking for is something like that:

```
if(in_array($first_array,$second_array)){echo 0;}else{echo 1;}
```

Comment: See [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

Comment: $exist_now = array_intersect($needed,$availaible);      $check =array_diff($needed,$exist_now); and check if $check is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function check_similar($actual, $expected) {
    if(!is_array($actual) && !is_array($expected))
        return false;
    $minLength = count($actual);
    if(count($expected) < $minLength)
        $minLength = count($expected);
    $index = 0;

    foreach($actual as $arr) {
        if(in_array($arr, $expected)) 
            $index++;
    }

    if($index >= $minLength)
        return true;
    return false;
}

$arr1 = ['1','2','3'];
$arr2 = ['1','2','3','4'];
var_dump(check_similar($arr1, $arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function array_diff()

`echo array_diff($needed, $whatwehave) ? 1 : 0;`

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php